# Break timer win32 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, animation, winapi, 3d

I am trying to create an animation loop through the use of timers. I want to call a different `SetRenderParams(int)` after approximately 5-10 seconds. I don't know how timers work and the documentation I can find online is VERY minimal.

I tried `if` and `while` statements to break the timer, but I have come to understand it does not work as a loop, so it cannot check counts. I am never able to move to `IDT_TIMER2`. I am thinking I might not need multiple timers, since I do not mind keeping the same animation speed (which is what the timer essentially accomplices), but a way to alternate `SetRenderParams(int)` without breaking from the timer, maybe(?).

I checked `timerqueues` as well, but while I was checking them I got more and more confused... The link I followed to come this far was the following, however this one does not show a way to input multiple animations in sequence, only one. To be clear, I do not want to have multiple animations at the same time. I want animation after animation, distinct from each other. http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/animation.html

The code I posted is clear from all the experiments I tried.

```cpp
LRESULT Framework::MsgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Set two timers. 
    const int IDT_TIMER1 = 1;
    const int IDT_TIMER2 = 2;
    SetTimer(hWnd,             // handle to main window 
        IDT_TIMER1,            // timer identifier 
        50,       // 10-second interval 
        NULL);     // no timer callback 

    SetTimer(hWnd,             // handle to main window 
        IDT_TIMER2,            // timer identifier 
        20000,                // five-minute interval 
        NULL);     // no timer callback 

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        //=== Add code for Rendering Models);
        RenderScene(hdc);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;

    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        int count = 0;
        RECT rcClient;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        switch (wParam)
        {

        case    IDT_TIMER1:
            SetRenderParams(13);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            break;
        case  IDT_TIMER2:
            SetRenderParams(14);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            break;
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit: forgot to add the initialized variables.

edit: providing a link to the .sln file https://www.mediafire.com/file/x42hy751n89z5bf/Rasteriser.zip/file

Comment: It seems that you posted code fragments, but not complete code. Please post at least the entire window procedure.

Comment: And why you call GetDC/ReleaseDC in WM_TIMER if you dont use hdc?

Comment: Animation 101: **Always** store the time point of the animation start, and use that time point and the current time to determine what (and how) to render the current step. This makes the animation framerate-independent, and conveniently solves your issue.

Comment: @IInspectable So something like this  I suppose? Still does not move to the next animation.
`time_t now = time(0);
time_t anim = time(NULL) + 10;
switch (wParam)
{

case  IDT_TIMER1:
 now = time(0);

 SetRenderParams(13);
 InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
 if (now > anim)
 {
  SetRenderParams(14);
  InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
 }
 //ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
 break;`

Comment: @RaymondChen It's too much code to post here, I could post a zip with the .sln file, if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Just the window procedure, not the whole program.

Comment: You call `SetTimer` each time the window procedure is called, so every time your window receives *any* message, you start a new timer. You want to start the timer once, say, when the window is created.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a "solution" but it is really grindy code. I create an `Update` method with clocks in it and then I call in inside the `WM_TIMER` . I have to manually input all the `clock` commands and since I have around 20 `SetRenderParams`, we are talking about very unoptimized program. Here is the code:

```
void Framework::UpdateCube(HWND hWnd)
{
    clock_t  t;
    t = clock();
    if (t < 10000.0f)
    {
        SetRenderParams(13);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        t = clock();
    }
    if (t >= 10000.0f && t < 10100.0f)
    {
        SetRenderParams(10);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
    if (t >= 10100.0f && t < 20100.0f)
    {
        SetRenderParams(15);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
    if (t >= 20100.0f && t < 20200.0f)
    {
        SetRenderParams(10);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
}
```

.
.
.

```
case WM_TIMER:
{

    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
    UpdateCube(hWnd);
}
break;
```